# AngularJs Redirecting the request to Subdomain

Tags: angularjs, redirect, asp.net-web-api, subdomain

Hi I am working on a classified site using `AngularJs SPA` and `Web Api`. The requirement from my client is:

When the first request comes from the browser on our domain (`www.mydomain.com`), it should be redirected to the requested country subdomain like `uae.mydomain.com` (If request is coming from UAE), `usa.mydomain.com` (if request is coming from USA), `china.mydomain.com` (if request is coming from china).

I am searching over google for quite a long time now and I am surprised that not much help is available which can guide me to the right direction. Please show me the right direction.

Comment: Use an IP address lookup service to find out what the country is

Comment: I don't understand, can you please explain a little bit in detail?

Comment: There are numerous IP address services that you can send user's IP to and find out origin country in response. Every http request includes user's ip